# CCLabel text alignment and breakmode

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, alignment, label, line-breaks

I'm trying to use hAlignment and lineBreakMode on a CCLabelTTF but the compiler don't like CCTextAlignmentCenter - CCLineBreakModeWordWrap and don't like UITextAlignmentCenter - UILineBreakModeWrap too.

I don't know how to solve this ...

Here my code if you want an example :

```
 CCLabelTTF *bubbleLabel1 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"My string." 
                                                       dimensions:CGSizeMake(200, 120) 
                                                       hAlignment:CCTextAlignmentCenter 
                                                    lineBreakMode:CCLineBreakModeWordWrap 
                                                         fontName:@"EngraversMT" fontSize:14];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I just found how to solve this. You have to prefix your mode with a "k" (for constant).

Here the same example but now it works :

```
CCLabelTTF *bubbleLabel1 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"My string." 
                                                   dimensions:CGSizeMake(200, 120) 
                                                   hAlignment:kCCTextAlignmentCenter 
                                                lineBreakMode:kCCLineBreakModeWordWrap 
                                                     fontName:@"EngraversMT" fontSize:14];
```